# Async calls inside typescript constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, typeorm

I'm trying to convert my monolithic node project into a microservice. I'm using typeorm to persist data onto my MySQL database. In here, when I try to initialize a service class, I'm trying to inject the repository correspond to that service in the service class constructor. Since typeorm library's repository find method is an asynchronous call, I'm struggling to do this. Can somebody suggest me a way to do this or any alternatives to implement this microservice architecture with typeorm. Thanks.

**Service class**

```
class TuitionService {

    private tutionRepository: Repository<Tuition>;

    private constructor() {
        this.tutionRepository = getTuitionRepository();
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
export function getTuitionRepository(): any {
    return async function getRepository(): Promise<Repository<Tuition>> {
        return await MySQLDataSource.getRepository(Tuition);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `getTuitionRepository` function you're calling from the constructor in the code above is synchronous, so there's no issue with calling it from the constructor. That function *returns* an asynchronous function, but it does that synchronously. It's only if you call the function it returns (`this.tutionRepository`) that you're dealing with an asynchronous call. (Side note: You're missing an `i` in `tutionRepository`.)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. Can you please enlighten me on this as I’m not good with Promises. In this case will the getTuitionRepository method will return Repository of type tuition or simply a Promise. If so is there any way to initialize the constructor variable with the resolved data of the Promise.

Comment: The `getTuitionRepository` function above will return a function, not a promise. (The function it returns will return a promise if you call it.)